# How to pass parameters to procedure in SSRS?

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a table like this:

```
create table emp(empid, empname, sal)

insert emp values(101, 'srewt', 1500)
```

The table contains 10000 rows.

I also have a stored procedure like this:

```
create procedure p1 (@eid int)
as
begin
   select * from emp where empid = @eid)
end
```

In SSRS I execute this procedure

```
exec p1 (' ')
```

but I have to provide user interaction to the report to pass `empid` value (nothing but parameter)

How can I pass a parameter to the report?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the parameter in the report designer. Open the report data tab (should be in the same place, as the solution explorer. if it is not there, you can show the report data dock by opening a report, clicking on View-ReportData).

When you double click on the report dataset, you can configure the report parameters. If you chose a stored procedure with parameters as datasource, the designer should detect the parameters of the procedure automatically and fill in the values in the parameter tab for you. But make sure to check the data type, as the detected data types often are not the ones you really need.

Comment: actually in my reql requirement , my procedure contains 40 parameters but user have to pass values only for one parameter i.e remaining 39 parameters should not passed by the client or user. how can i use only one parameter instead of giving 39 parameters

Comment: can any one help me how to pass the perticuler parameters to the procedure

Comment: Hi Tom , will u see my requirement once again and share your thoughts

Comment: Ah ok, the 40 parameters where not stated in the original question. I think hermanth's answer should help you there. Instead of using query type STORED_PROCEDURE you can use the query type Text and then simply call the stored procedure by hand with one parameter (@EmpID). Then only this parameter will be created in the parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

In your dataset just pass `exec p1 (@EmpID)` as a query, then automatically a parameter with name EmpID will be created in Report. Here when user run the report it asks for EmpID to enter, just give the ID and run the report...

Comment: hemanth can you tell how can i restrict 10 records for each page.

Comment: Add a row grouping for the table as "=ceiling(rownumber(nothing)/10)" and in group properties select the option "Add page break on each instance of group"...